# iOS storyboard localization

Tags: ios, localization, storyboard

I want to **localize** my **storyboard**. Few of the views in my app have to be localized, previously I used to create two views and choose one with

```
        initwithnibname
```

but i dont know how should i do it with the storyboard. Do i have to make different  storyboards for different languages??

Comment: is there any way to make similar changes in all the localized storyboard by making change in any one of them??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got the answer.. just added a localization language to storyboard and a new storyboard was made for new language.. :)